# SQL update statement in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to update a field in my table using Netbeans and I have two conditions. The update statement is as follows:

```
String sql1 = "update tbl_log set Logout_Time =? where Firstname = ? and Check = ?";
        try{
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            pst.setString(1, time);
            pst.setString(2, username);
            pst.setString(3, "IN");
            pst.execute();
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

but I am getting the following error:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQL SyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Check = 'IN' at line 1

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is `time` really a string field in the database?

Comment: Add-on question to @Jon's: why are you storing a time in a string? `:(`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Check" is a reserved word, so you need to put it in backticks

Change it to:

```
String sql1 = "update tbl_log set Logout_Time =? where Firstname = ? and `Check` = ?";
```

For a list of reserved words, see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @Ravi77. If you have problems updating Logout_Time, it is probably because you are using the wrong data type for that column. Change it to "Datetime" for example. You will have to convert the time variable to a Date, and call `pst.setDate(1, time)`. Alternative solution: If you only want to set Logout_Time to the current time, you can change the query to `update tbl_log set Logout_Time =NOW() where Firstname = ? and \`Check\` = ?` (assuming that you have already changed the type of the Logout_Time column to "Datetime"). In this case you don't have to think of the "time" variable at all

Comment: @Optimist. That's not necessary if you have converted it to "datetime" and remember to set it to "NOW()". MySQL will automatically fill in the field using the current time

Comment: @Optimist. i am creating a system to record the login time and logout time of a user. when the user login the username,login time is store in the table tbl_log and when the user logout the logout time should be save in the table... if 1 set the data type of column logout_time to "datetime". when the user login is returns me an error "java.sql.SQLException: Field 'Logout_Time' doesn't have a default value"

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`pst.executeUpdate();`

and also

is `pst` a `PreparedStatement`? 
if not change it to that...

Comment: Of course `pst` is a `PreparedStatement`; that's what `Connection#prepareStatement()` returns.

Answer (score -1):

```
st.executeUpdate("update reservation set busname='"           +
                  jTextField10.getText() + "',busno='"        +
                  jTextField9.getText()  + "',cusname='"      + 
                  jTextField8.getText()  + "',noofpass='"     +
                  jTextField7.getText()  + "',amount='"       +
                  jTextField6.getText()  +"' where cusname='" +
                  jTextField8.getText()  + "' ");
```